# Nonlinear PDE solver

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, finite-element-method, nonlinear

I would like to solve the following nonlinear PDE:

$$
\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x^2} - \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial t^2} = \lambda |\phi|^2 \phi
$$

I was trying:

```
NDSolve[{D[f[x, t], x, x] - D[f[x, t], t, t] == f[x, t]^3, f[x, 0] == Sin[2*Pi*x], f[0, t] == 0, f[1, t] == 0}, f, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

but, I am consistenly getting `NDSolve::femnonlinear: Nonlinear coefficients are not supported in this version of NDSolve`.

Is there any solver for non-linear PDEs?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The error message is misleading.  `NDSolve` fails, because not enough boundary conditions in `t` have been supplied.  If, for instance, `(D[f[x, t], t] /. t -> 0) == 0` is added, then

```
sol = First@NDSolve[{D[f[x, t], x, x] - D[f[x, t], t, t] == f[x, t]^3, 
    f[x, 0] == Sin[2*Pi*x], (D[f[x, t], t] /. t -> 0) == 0, 
    f[0, t] == 0, f[1, t] == 0}, f, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}];
```

yields

```
Plot3D[f[x, t] /. sol, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {x, t, f}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 12]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In version 12.0 you can also solve this with the FEM:

```
NDSolveValue[{D[f[x, t], x, x] - D[f[x, t], t, t] == f[x, t]^3, 
  f[x, 0] == Sin[2*Pi*x], (D[f[x, t], t] /. t -> 0) == 0, 
  f[0, t] == 0, f[1, t] == 0}, f, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, 
 Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
   "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement"}}]
```

Plot the difference between the solutions:

```
Plot3D[(f[x, t] /. sol) - solFEM[x, t], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]